What is the proper handling of Queue string memory
I built my own TaskQueue for my multi-threaded program but there is an error on the allocation of memory somewhere in the code.
In main.c:
#include <pthread.h>
#include <task_queue.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <curl.h>

typedef struct Threadargs {
   TaskQueue *q; 
   CURLM *multi_handle;
   pthread_mutex_t lock;
} Threadargs;

void *do_task(void *args);

int main(){
   int len = 5;
   char *arr[] = {
      "filename.txt",
      "endpoint",
      "endpoint",
      "endpoint",
      "endpoint"
   };
   TaskQueue *q = queueFromArr(arr, 1, len);
   
   curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);
   CURLM *multi_handle = curl_multi_init();
   curl_multi_setopt(multi_handle, CURLMOPT_PIPELINING, CURLPIPE_MULTIPLEX);
   
   Threadargs *targs = malloc(sizeof(Threadargs));
   targs->q = q;
   targs->multi_handle = multi_handle;
   pthread_mutex_init(&targs->lock, NULL);

   pthread_t threads[len];
   for(int i = 0; i < len; ++i){
      pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, do_task, q);
   }
   int still_running = 0;
   do{
        pthread_mutex_lock(&handle->lock);
        int pres = curl_multi_perform(handle->multi_handle, &still_running);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&handle->lock);

        if(pres != CURLM_OK){
            //print error here
            break;
        }

        int wres = curl_multi_poll(handle->multi_handle, NULL, 0, 1000, &numfds);
        if(wres != CURLM_OK){
           //print error here 
           break;
        }

        if (numfds == 0) {
            usleep(100000);
        }
    } while (still_running);

    pthread_mutex_lock(&targs->lock);
    while((msg = curl_multi_info_read(multi_handle, &msgs_left)) != NULL){
       pthread_mutex_unlock(&targs->lock);

       CURL *easy_handle = msg->easy_handle;
       CURLcode return_code = msg->data.result; // for log file
          
            
       if(validateMulti(handle) != CURLM_OK) 
          return CURLM_BAD_HANDLE;
       if(easy_handle == NULL) 
          return CURLM_BAD_EASY_HANDLE;

       CURLMcode res;
       pthread_mutex_lock(&handle->lock);
       res = curl_multi_remove_handle(handle->multi_handle, easy_handle); // for debug
       pthread_mutex_unlock(&handle->lock);
       
       char *url;
       if(curl_easy_getinfo(easy_handle, CURLINFO_PRIVATE, &url) != CURLE_OK) {
          //print error here
          continue;
       }
       free(url);
       curl_easy_cleanup(easy_handle);

       pthread_mutex_lock(&targs->lock);
       }
   pthread_mutex_unlock(&targs->lock);
    

   for(int i = 0; i < len; ++i){
      pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
   }

   free(threads);
   pthread_mutex_destroy(&targs->lock);
   return 0;
}
void *do_task(void *args){
   Threadargs *targs = (Threadargs*)args; 
   TaskQueue *q = targs->q;
   CURLM *multi = targs->multi_handle;
   char *endpoint; 
   while((endpoint = (char *)queueDequeue(queue)) != NULL){ //error is here
      CURL *handle = curl_easy_init();
      
      // set options for curl
      curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURLOPT_URL, endpoint);

      pthead_mutex_lock(&targs->lock);
      CURLcode res = curl_multi_add_handle(multi, handle);
      pthread_mutex_unlock(&targs->lock);
      
      if(res != CURLM_OK){
         // print out error here
         return (void *) 1;
      }
   }
   return (void *) 0;
}


In task_queue.c:
//#include <stdlib.h>
//#include <stdio.h>
//#include <string.h>
typedef struct Task{
    char *endpoint;
    struct Task *next;
} Task;

typedef struct TaskQueue{
    Task *head;
    Task *tail;
    pthread_mutex_t lock;
} TaskQueue;
TaskQueue *queueInit() {
    TaskQueue *tqueue = malloc(sizeof(TaskQueue));
    if(!tqueue)
        return NULL;
    tqueue->head = NULL;
    tqueue->tail = NULL;
    pthread_mutex_init(&tqueue->lock,NULL);
    return tqueue;
}
void queueEnqueue(TaskQueue *queue, char *endpoint) {
    Task *task = malloc(sizeof(Task));
    task->endpoint = endpoint;
    task->next = NULL;

    pthread_mutex_lock(&queue->lock);

    if (queue->tail == NULL)
    {
        queue->head = queue->tail = task;
    }
    else
    {
        queue->tail->next = task;
        queue->tail = task;
    }

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&queue->lock);
}

TaskQueue *queueFromArr(char **arr, int start, int end) {
    TaskQueue *queue;
    if((queue = queueInit()) == NULL)
        return NULL;
    for(int i = start; i < end; ++i){
        char *point = strdup(arr[i]);
        queueEnqueue(queue,point);
    }
    return queue;
}

// Dequeue a task from the queue
void *queueDequeue(TaskQueue *queue) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&queue->lock);

    if (queue->head == NULL) {
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&queue->lock);
        return NULL; 
    }

    Task *temp = queue->head;
    char *data = strdup(temp->endpoint); 
    queue->head = temp->next;

    if (queue->head == NULL)
        queue->tail = NULL;

    free(temp); 
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&queue->lock);
    return data; 
}

The line in the do_task function: while((endpoint = (char *)queueDequeue(queue)) != NULL){
causes the following error:
==62212== 440 bytes in 5 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 147 of 510
==62212==    at 0x484DA83: calloc (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==62212==    by 0x1204675E: make_call (main.c:316)
==62212==    by 0x4A36AC2: start_thread (pthread_create.c:442)
==62212==    by 0x4AC7A03: clone (clone.S:100)

I originally thought it had something to do with the strdup but, normally, if it was the memory allocated by it - it would say strdup was the memory allocator. I may be wrong though. The leak is happening somewhere even though endpoint is properly freed upon completion of the tasks.
EDIT: added all information requested, and simplest example to reciprocate results via requests from comments.
As well as added includes to the .c file to make sure proper access was made to all functions within and noted where the error is occurring.
Majority of the post clarification edited by @Fe2O3

Without seeing the code that allocated the object being destroyed, there's no way we can tell if free(temp) is sufficient to deallocate it. How was temp->endpoint allocated? Who freed it?

Edit the question to provide a [mre].

Wild guess: after strdup() (for some reason), probably want free( temp->endpoint ); Can't tell because OP hasn't revealed what a struct TaskQueue looks like...

@DavidSchwartz Sorry for my lack of information, Ive added all of that information. While it is a minimum, it is a lot.

I can't immediately see themake_call valgrind mentions, and I don't know which is line 316 in main.c - presumably you can see this easily, so would you mind pointing it out?

Originally, the post only had line 316 in the post, but I changed it to have the code reproduceable. Line 316 is while((endpoint = (char *)queueDequeue(queue)) != NULL){. I will make an edit to clarify

By editing the question, you're invalidating part of an answer that has been provided to you... That's gratitude??

@Fe2O3 I, by no means, mean to discredit you. The answers provided though, are not fixing the question being asked and more of me re-implementation of my code with least lines(not talking about the heap allocation). I will credit you in the post to make sure your help clarifying is noticed. Sorry about that.

Fe2O3 respectfully declines credit for any/all/absent revisions to OP's code.

The line 316 of main.c that Valgrind is talking about is not while((endpoint = (char *)queueDequeue(queue)) != NULL){.  At least, not the one currently presented in the question.  The line in question appears inside a function named make_call, which is not evident in your code at all.

Ignoring that the extended posting of more code is incomplete and incorrect:
char *arr = {
      "filename.txt",
      "endpoint",
      "endpoint",
      "endpoint",
      "endpoint"
   };


queueEnqueue() has an unverified call to malloc(). And that's not the only location where good fortune is being trusted.

It's good to read your code and think about its operations..
TaskQueue *queueFromArr(char **arr, int start, int end) {
    /* stuff */
    char *point = strdup(arr[i]); // <= FIRST heap allocation (making a copy)
    queueEnqueue(queue,point);

... then ...
void *queueDequeue(TaskQueue *queue) {
    /* stuff */
    char *data = strdup(temp->endpoint); // a SECOND allocated copy (why?)

    /* stuff */

    free(temp); // <= abandoning the FIRST allocated block (memory leak)

Apart from overlooking verification of malloc() success, the OP should become aware that strdup() may return NULL also. Too much confidence that things always go according to plan.

The OP's oversight would, perhaps, be more apparent if the code were lightly simplified:
TaskQueue *queueFromArr(char **arr, int start, int end) {
    TaskQueue *queue;
    if((queue = queueInit()) == NULL)
        return NULL;
    for(int i = start; i < end; ++i)
        queueEnqueue( queue, arr[i] ); // <== HERE
    return queue;
}

And...
void queueEnqueue(TaskQueue *queue, char *endpoint) {
    Task *task = malloc(sizeof(Task));
    task->endpoint = strdup( endpoint ); // <== HERE
    task->next = NULL;
    /* more stuff */

This change makes obvious the heap allocation of a buffer. Its subsequent duplication into another buffer might stand out as an opportune time to free() the first instance.
Both malloc() and strdup() returned values need to be verified before being used.
void *queueDequeue(TaskQueue *queue) {
    /* stuff */
    char *data = strdup(temp->endpoint); // a SECOND allocated copy (why?)

    /* stuff */

    free(temp); // <= abandoning the FIRST allocated block (memory leak)

If multi-thread "ownership" of the memory is an issue, that's a problem for the OP to address in their larger concept and design.

Oops. It is in task_queue.c

Are you using a header file for the task_queue.c to reproduce? Why is there an unverified call to malloc?

Re: "unverified call to malloc" Examine the first 3 lines of void queueEnqueue().

@Fe203 Oh you mean that I didn't check that the memory was allocated. I just typed all of this up - its not exactly what was in my program, but just assume each of those malloc calls succeeds (otherwise I'd have an invalid read)

Pointless asking an editor to fix your story, and providing an abridged version (without chapters 3, 7 and 11...)

I only provided the line causing the error and the direct function call originally because I believed that it was my misunderstanding of the assignment, because the error notes that assignment allocated that information instead of the strdup which should be doing allocating. Well, whether you are happy or not for helping me fix my post and learn more about asking questions on here(4th or something post), I really do appreciate your time and effort helping me.

"(otherwise I'd have an invalid read)" No, you'd have written an invalid C program, and it would exhibit UB. That means, it might appear to work through all your testing, but suddenly and mysteriously crash the day you present it to the paying client... Your call. Some people are concerned about their reputation at the office or in business.

Its checked in my product code... Like I said, assume it succeeds for the sake of the question which is not directly asking about that...

Q's title: "What is the proper handling of ... memory" Your call. Is the Q asking about "proper handling" or is it not... As I wrote, it's pointless to post code that is NOT the code that exhibits the problem...

Fair enough. Maybe I should have named it something else. But I only posted code that was the code that exhibits the problem.

@BaccaRulerMC A word of advice. Whether or not your actual code is properly checking return values for graceful handling of problems, there's this: It takes only a few seconds to type the few lines that detect & handle problems when the code is 100 lines and growing. It can take more than a few DAYS to track down a bug in code "that's been working up 'til now" when the code has grown to 1000+ lines and it first encounters the Gb of data it's meant to process... Be kind to your future self.

I appreciate the advice; the code is already around 2000 lines. I wish I had this reminder when I started out making this program. I never planned on it becoming greater than 300 lines let alone a thousand but I had forgot how quickly that can change. It can take more than a few DAYS to track down a bug in code "that's been working up 'til now": Real, this has what I have been doing for the past few days of work. Thanks again for your advice/guidance.

@BaccaRulerMC This is what they mean when they say, "Never stop learning." :-) Sounds like you're in the midst of a lesson right now. Good luck, and hope you resolve the problem soon... then clear sailing... until the next one arises... :-)
